# Unable to catch JsonMappingException

Tags: java, jackson

My IDE is giving me the error `Unhandled Exception com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException` with the `mapper.readValue` line

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    if (response.isEmpty()) {
        //Http 204 (No Content) returned from MCC
        //We should handle this differently
        user = new User();
    } else {
        user = mapper.readValue(response, User.class);
    }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, ioe.getLocalizedMessage());
}
return user;
```

I've tried catching the `JsonMappingException` but it didn't make the error go away.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to add a catch block for the specific type of Exception. Try `catch(JsonMappingException jme){}`

Comment: I tried that... when I do that, it says `Required: java.lang.Throwable` as if that Exception can't be thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JsonMappingException` extends `IOException`, so your IDE is having some deeper trouble of its own -- perhaps library imports are messed up?

Comment: So what was the actual issue here?

Comment: Actually if you use org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException it extends JsonProcessingException and this one is missing in the package. That's the problem.

Comment: I've added response - just manually downlaoded jars and added into classpatch: jackson-annotations-2.1.2, com.fasterxml.jackson.core, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind It woks fine now.

Answer (score 12):

I got this problem when I ONLY added `jackson-mapper-asl` jar. When I added `jackson-core-asl` jar it worked.

This is true for Jackson 2 as well. This error occurs if you only include `jackson-databind`. You need to include `jackson-core` as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem because org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException extends JsonProcessingException (not any Throwable directly) and this one is missing in the package. After doing some research I've downloaded jars directly (not with Maven) and manually added them into classpatch:

- jackson-annotations-2.1.2
- com.fasterxml.jackson.core
- com.fasterxml.jackson.databind

Combination of this 3 packages solves this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It seems the class inherited by the `JsonMappingException` class is not in the JAR file. I just reverted to version 1.9 which didn't have the problem.

Answer (score 1):

i had same problem, when i added [json-core](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.3/), it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this as well?

`user = mapper.readValue(response.getEntity(String.class),User.class);`

PS: Assuming, `response` is of type `com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse`.

Comment: `String response = responseBuilder.toString();`

Comment: What is the value of the `response` you get?

Comment: I currently haven't yet run the application, it's my IDE that's throwing the error.

Comment: @Webnet: You are catching the wrong exception perhaps? Were you catching `org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException` instead of `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException`?

Answer (score 0):

Add jackson-core-asl.jar, it will work