# How to handel JsonMappingException try catch

Tags: java, json, jackson, try-catch

I am new to jackson, i have written this code and my ide says at catch block .
I dont understand this . I have included jar.

```
     incompatible types
     required:java.lang.Throwable
     found :org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException
```

This is the method

```
  private void jacksonTest()   {
    try {
        org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper mapper = new org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper();
            mapper.writeValue(new File("c:\\user.json"), someObj);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GR_XX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (JsonMappingException ex) {
//     incompatible types
//             required:java.lang.Throwable
//            found :org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GR_XX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GR_XX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Change the order of the first two catch blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from stackoverflow.com/a/14920842/2194456

I had the same issue. It seems the class inherited by the JsonMappingException class is not in the JAR file. I just reverted to version 1.9 which didn't have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [documentation of `JsonMappingException`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/JsonMappingException.html), it is a subclass of `IOException`. This means your first `catch` would already handle the `JsonMappingException`. If you want to handle it seperately, you'll have to catch it before `IOException`.

Comment: I got answer from http://stackoverflow.com/a/14920842/2194456 , Thanks for your help

Comment: @LMK then you should delete your question

Comment: Stannek , yea , i thought of deleting ,it gives a warning We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so deprives future readers of this knowledge.

Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?

Comment: @LMK I wrote my answer before I saw the duplicates. In my opinion this question and the answers don't add any more information to the duplicates so I would say it's fine to delete it. But others might see it differently. Maybe just close-vote on your on question because of duplicate?

Comment: Stannek , now i had deleted , it says "Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead." and i had flaged it

Answer (score 0):

In case of Multiple catch Exception Hierarchy comes into action

Try something like this :

```
try {
           ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
           mapper.writeValue(new File("c:\\user.json"), someObj.class);

       }

       catch (JsonMappingException ex) {  }
       catch (IOException ex) {}
       catch (Exception ex) {}
       catch (Throwable ex) {}
```

Comment: I got answer from http://stackoverflow.com/a/14920842/2194456 , Thanks for your help